# Merging nodes from minimum heap pointer issues

Tags: c++, pointers

So I am trying to merge nodes from my minimum heap until there is only one node remaining in my minimum heap. For example:

Minimum Heap:
A
B
C
D

How it should look like afterwards:
ABCD

After merging A and B, we get AB. Then AB with C, so we get ABC, then ABC with D so the final node is ABCD. Here is my node structure:

```
struct Node {
  std::string letter;
  int frequency;

  Node* leftPtr;
  Node* rightPtr;
};
```

and here is my code that merges the nodes

```
while (heapSize != 1) {
    left = peek ();
    right = peek ();
    top.letter = left.letter + right.letter;
    top.frequency = left.frequency + right.frequency;
    top.leftPtr = &left;
    top.rightPtr = &right;
    addElement(top);
}
```

Lets say I want to print the node 'AB', I would say

```
cout << heap[0].leftPtr->letter << endl;
```

This works, however,

```
cout << heap[0].leftPtr->leftPtr->letter << endl;
```

still gives me back AB and I'm not sure why. This should give A and not AB.

**Note* Peek() returns the top element from the Minimum Heap and addElement() adds a Node to the heap **

Comment: Hum... I don't understand, the `top` struct is the top of the heap, right ? So, why do you use `heap[0]` and not `top` ? Are they equivalent ? A scope problem ?

Comment: @Apitronix top is the parent of the left and right children. heap[0] is the first (and only) node in the heap after running the while loop.